# Eclipse CDT, CMAKE project: No C/C++ Build Menu Item

Tags: c++, cmake, eclipse-cdt

Thanks in advance for the help.

This is on Windows/MSYS2 (mingw64) Eclipse CDT Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) Build id: 20190917-1200.

I have figured out how to run cmake in order to create an Eclipse compatible project file. I then got the project into Eclipse via I got this File->Open Project from File System. I can then make/build that file and create my executables. I do get a couple warnings regarding improper project path but the code all compiles without error.

However, I need to "connect" the cmake build directory (i.e. the project in Kicad) to my source code in order to edit and/or debug the changes I wish to make. Based on my research I believe I have to do this via the Project Properties C/C++ Build menu, however, this menu is not present. I believe I access this menu by selecting the project on the left and right clicking or alt-enter or from the top menu Project->Properties.

For some reason I can't do a screen grab on Eclipse but I pulled the image attached from the online help file:  (https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp)

[image].

My "Project->Properties" menu looks similar in that it shows Resource, Builders, plus more things but there is no C/C++ Build entry: it just goes from Builders to C/C++ General.

I found this "solution" https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508319 which seemed appropriate as I had installed the standalone debugger, however, uninstalling it had no effect.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: How did you created the eclipse project using cmake?

Comment: I actually more or less solved this issue. See https://documenteddesigns.com/2019/11/22/building-kicad-on-windows-10-with-eclipse-msys2/ which provides complete instructions.

I never figured out where the missing menus are but otherwise everything works OK.

Thanks